# Eclipse RCP application set default css & theme for macOS

Tags: eclipse-rcp

We want to add two css stylesheets, each for macOS and windows. I have added the following property to the extension point org.eclipse.core.runtime.products in the plugin.xml.

```xml
<property
        name="cssTheme"
        value="com.my.id.css.theme">
</property>
```

Have also added two entries for theme as below

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme">
      <theme
            basestylesheeturi="css/style.css"
            id="com.my.id.css.theme"
            label="wincss"
            os="win32">
      </theme>
      <theme
            basestylesheeturi="css/macstyle.css"
            id="com.my.id.css.theme"
            label="maccss"
            os="macosx">
      </theme>
   </extension>
```

On startup of eclipse rcp application the maccss theme is not selected by default. Although in windows 11, the wincss is default theme selected.

In macos , when we open Preferences > General > Appearance and theme is manually changed to maccss then the desired styling is appearing.

Comment: Note: Once a preference has been set for a theme that is remembered and will continue to be used. Are you testing with a new workspace that has not had a theme preference set?

Comment: `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine#initializeStyling` is the code that sets up the theme you could debug that.

Comment: We found out the issue. Basically the mac os dark theme was taking preference over the theme set in plugin.xml. When we switched to the mac os default theme, then the desired theme is getting applied.